# Render HTML/Execute JavaScript in C# Console Application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am having an html page like this:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://......someFile.js"> </script>
        <script>
            function CallJs()
            {
                var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
                document.write(decodedCookie);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="CallJs();">
       
    </body>
    </html>
```

If I execute this page on a browser I get the desired result.  But I want to execute the JavaScript code written in this page without using a browser.  I want to execute it on a C# console application.

Is there any way of doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use msscriptcontrol in this situation. You can check below thread:

[How do I call an external JScript function from a VB.NET console application?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxjscript/thread/e43012b2-8d72-423a-99bd-c6a4ef358077)

You can also check the article below which may help you.

[Make your .Net application support scripting - a practical approach](http://osherove.com/blog/2004/2/17/make-your-net-application-support-scripting-a-practical-appr.html)