# C# console application call Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

As title.  I am developing a GIS system.  In order to test my new developed feature, I want to send data to my new developed page, so I need to call a JavaScript inside a certain JS file.  I've made a console EXE application to make me easy to choose test data to send to my new feature,  but I can't find a way to call my JavaScript function to send test data to activate my new feature.

I've read this:[Render HTML/Execute JavaScript in C# Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716153/render-html-execute-javascript-in-c-sharp-console-application) , but I've read the answer, one link with Microsoft Script Control gives my application an error about InterOp, and I can't understand the other because of my poor English.

Could someone guide me a way to make it?

Comment: You could use ASP.net with C# and provide your javascript an API it can read the data from using the `fetch` function in JavaScript

Comment: Is your developed page with the web page and js running on a ASP.Net or .Net Core environment?

Comment: Console Application using .NET Framework under Windows 10 (traditional desktop environment)